# Библиотеки для Decision Tree

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Задача построит Decision Tree Regression используя разные библиотеки. Не знаете ли вы библиотеки для DT? Мне нужно лишь название библиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно же, первым делом нужно смотреть в `sklearn`:

- классический [DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html)
- чуть более сложный [ExtraTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeRegressor.html)

Ну а после них уже можно переходить к ансамблям из множества деревьев в том же `sklearn`:

- случайный лес [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)
- ещё вариант случайных деревьев [ExtraTreesRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesRegressor.html)

Answer (score 0):

В наше время практически никто уже не использует одиночные деревья решений - все пользуются ансамблями деревьев.

Наиболее популярными из ансамблей деревьев, на мой взгляд, являются:

- [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [CatBoost](https://github.com/catboost/tutorials)
- [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html)

PS  леса (или ансамбли деревьев) используют множество одиночных деревьев решений и поэтому формально подходят для вашей задачи.

Comment: А для регрессий можно использовать?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, да, по-моему, у всех указанных в ответе библиотек также существует API для регрессионных прогнозов. Вот только я не уверен, что для задач регрессии ансамбли деревьев это лучший подход... Тут без знания ваших данных трудно дать полезный совет

Comment: Просто у меня задача именно построит дерево решений используя разные библиотеки. Не знаете ли вы библиотеки для DT?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, ну так и укажите задачу в вопросе, чтобы мы не гадали

Comment: Извините думал понятно, добавил.

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin, а где в вопросе информация о самой задаче, о регрессии и т.д.?

Comment: @MaxU Нуу, вообще-то бустинги хотя часто и основаны на решающих деревьях, но в общем случае они не обязаны быть основанными именно на них. Суть бустингов в другом. А основу, над которой делается бустинг, там обычно можно переключать в настройках. В частности у XGBoost точно можно. Я не к тому, что ответ неправильный, но он не совсем точный без указания того, что бустинг - это вообще-то не обязательно решающие деревья :)  Но что бустинги - это модно и современно, тут без вариантов, конечно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, все указанные в моем ответе модули изначально строились на основе ансамблей решающих деревьев. И уже благодаря бустингам они  стали наиболее популярными и соответственно попали в данный ответ ) С чисто академической точки зрения, можно конечно поиграться с `DecisionTreeRegressor` и `ExtraTreeRegressor`, но на практике, IMO, это как делать анестезию при помощи деревянной дубинки :-D

Comment: @MaxU И всё же. Решающие деревья там довольно специфические :)  Что бустинги штука хорошая - я же и не спорю. )  И для обучения вообще-то хорошо бы начинать "плясать от печки" - линейная регрессия, решающие деревья... а потом уже можно и ансамбли, и там уже вообще не важно, что внутри ансамбля.

Comment: @CrazyElf, "и там уже вообще не важно, что внутри ансамбля" - с этим утверждением я в корне не согласен. Ансамбли строятся из "base learners" и в зависимости от алгоритма используемого в "base learners" мы и получим соответствующий результат. Решающие деревья, например, более устойчивые к категориальным значениям и часто не требуют "дорогостоящего" OneHotEncoding и т.д. Поэтому - важно что внутри ансамбля

Comment: @MaxU Вот про категориальные то переменные я и не подумал. Логично.

Comment: А для SVR какие библиотеки есть кроме sklearn?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin А зачем? SVM - очень специфические модели, сейчас их практически нигде не применяют. Они очень медленные (на порядок как минимум медленнее даже ансамблей, я уж не говорю про линейную регрессию), при этом преимуществ у них никаких нет перед другими моделями.

Comment: @CrazyElf Просто я сравниваю несколько видов модели с использованием нескольких библиотек. Если знаете можете сказать пожалуйста.

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin Честно говоря не знаю, пытался гуглить - тоже все пути ведут к `sklearn`. Единственное что можно сделать - попробовать задавать разные `kernel=` в `SVR` от `sklearn`, хоть какая-то вариация.